# Get geolocation of twitter hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, geolocation, hashtag

I like to get the geolocation from tweets that have the hashtag `#sun`. Everytime somebody tweets something with `#sun` I like to get a `console.log` with the coordinates of the tweet. How would an API request for that look like and how could I implement that with JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [Twitter's Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter).

```
POST    https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json
POST Data   track=#sun
```

That will get each Tweet streamed to you.  Look through the user entities and you will see the location (if the tweet has one).